# Merging 2000+ excel file into one big data frame

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, import-from-excel

I wrote a code to merge excel files into one big data frame. The code was working fine with small number of test files (<=200), but now when I am running the code on actual files (~2500) it gives me the following error.

***Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column***

```
    library(rJava)
    library (XLConnect)
    data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xls")
    df = readWorksheetFromFile(file=data.files[1], sheet=1, check.names=F) # Read the         first file

    # Loop through the remaining files and merge them to the existing data frame
    for (file in data.files[-1]) {
        newFile = readWorksheetFromFile(file=file, sheet=1, check.names=F)
    df = merge(df, newFile, all = TRUE, check.names=F)
    }

    write.csv(df, file="Collated_Raw_Files.csv")
```

I am very new to **R**. Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `by=` parameter is from the `merge` function. It tires to guess which values to merge your data.frames on by looking for columns with the same name in both. it sounds like you are winding up with repeated column names. This may have something to do with the fact that you've explicitly turned off `check.names` in your read statement so you're likely winding up with bad column names. Is there a single shared column name across all files to merge on? If so, explicitly set `by=` in `merge()`. All other column names unique? If not, this is still a problem.

Comment: As @MrFlick said, it's likely that the corrupt Excel file contains two columns with the same name, and it's also the column name on which `merge` tries to join. It fails because it doesn't know which one to pick from the 2 (or more).

Comment: Thanks MrFlick and lukeA. There was a duplicate column in one of the files and once I deleted it the code worked fine.